# Issues sorting and presenting my data - tapply and graphics issues

Tags: r, graph

I am currently attempting to present some data I collected in a placement experiment. Just something to get us going. We collected DNA from 12 soil samples each with three different treatments are were looking for 14 genes. There was also a limed/unlimed variable. R coding is both new and definitely not intuitive to me.

My actual aim is to present this data with the 14 genes (Gene) along the x axis and the DNA concentration (RelConc) on the Y axis. With dots (and maybe connecting lines) for each treatment matching the concentration against the gene to show the differences seen between treatments (Treatment). I was hoping to split the Limed and Unlimed data and put the two graphs on the same image.

This is a quick idea of what I want

[image]

Unfortunately the basic R tutorials have only gotten me as far as plots for Gene against RelConc and Treatment against RelConc.

Example of what I've got - Gene against DNA

[image]

My first thought was to create a new table containing only the data for one Treatment (such as the Control) and try and plot that separately.

I used

```
tapply(RelConc,Treatment, summary)
```

which worked fine and displayed summary concentration data separated by the treatments.

But I can't seem to get it to show just the Control, I have been trying variations along the lines of

```
tapply(RelConc,Treatment="Control", summary)
```

with a return of

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors
```

Any ideas are appreciated, in fact if there is a really simple way to do what I want that I am missing please let me know :)

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  Are you trying to subset the 'Treatment' to have only "Control".  In that case, there is no need for `tapply`

Comment: Yes exactly! I want to try and separate the three control methods so that I can plot them all as their own dots on the Gene to DNA graph. The idea was to use tapply to highlight each control individually and then assign that to a function. Then add each of them to the plot. I might just be asking google the wrong questions as I can't find out how.

Comment: The one showed in the handwritten paper can be done, but you have to show some reproducible example for others to test.

Comment: Okay I will try, shall I add my data set to the original post or do you require my current code? I am hoping to learn some of the ways to plot subsets of certain data columns, or perhaps cherry pick other types of data grouping from this experience for the future.

Comment: The boxplots imply there are multiple data for each gene-treatment combination. OTOH, saying you want to connect the points w/ lines for each treatment implies you are thinking of plotting a single value for each G-T combination. Are you wanting to plot some summary statistic (eg, mean or median), or did you want to do something else?

Comment: Yes! :) The genes have different concentrations depending on which treatment was used on the sample collected. So instead of box plots I would like to plot the individual points of each DNA concentration above the genes and mark them in a way that highlights which Treatment method was used in that sample. There would be 6 points for each gene with 3 treats and either limed or unlimed. I was hoping to also split the limed and unlimed to individual plots and display them together.

Comment: OK, I gather then that you have 6*14=84 observations of 4 variables. Can you just paste in your dataframe?

Comment: My apologies I worded that badly, there are 168 observations in total. 84 limed and 84 unlimed. A lot to paste but here is a link to the file on my gdrive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-_IN0mDhEdVTUFYZXRESHFqb2s/view?usp=sharing). I was hoping to get a good head start on the types of commands needed to subset data and then how to plot them all on the same graph

Comment: It's not that much to paste. So if there are multiple values (within a combination of DNA x Lim), do you want to plot the means or medians or something else? How do you want to handle multiple observations?

Comment: I was going to go with means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start. You can tweak the options as you like.  First, I wouldn't try anything like `tapply()`.  You need to get means for each specific combination; use `aggregate()` for that.  Then I'd make a one-off function for your plot to save some typing and for ease of editing. Note that you need a lot of custom features to get something like what you want.

```
d  <- read.csv(file=file.choose(), header=TRUE)
am <- aggregate(RelConc~Treatment*Gene*Liming, data=d, FUN=mean)

my.plot <- function(lim){
  with(am[which(am$Liming==lim & am$Treatment=="Control"),], 
       plot(x=as.numeric(Gene), y=RelConc, ylim=c(0, 0.1), type="b", pch=1, lty=1, col=1,
            axes=FALSE, main=lim, ylab="Relative Concentration", xlab=""))
  box()
  axis(side=1, at=1:14, labels=FALSE)
  text(x=1:14-.5, y=par("usr")[3]-.006, labels=levels(am$Gene), 
       srt=45, pos=1, xpd=TRUE, cex=.9)
  mtext(side=1, text="Gene", line=3.5)
  axis(side=2, at=seq(0, .1, by=.02), labels=seq(0, .1, by=.02))
  with(am[which(am$Liming==lim & am$Treatment=="Insecticide"),], 
       lines(x=as.numeric(Gene), y=RelConc, lty=2, col=2))
  with(am[which(am$Liming==lim & am$Treatment=="Insecticide"),], 
       points(x=as.numeric(Gene), y=RelConc, pch=2, col=2))
  with(am[which(am$Liming==lim & am$Treatment=="Molluscicide"),], 
       lines(x=as.numeric(Gene), y=RelConc, lty=3, col=4))
  with(am[which(am$Liming==lim & am$Treatment=="Molluscicide"),], 
       points(x=as.numeric(Gene), y=RelConc, pch=3, col=4))
  legend("topleft", legend=c("Control", "Insecticide", "Molluscicide"), 
         pch=1:3, lty=1:3, col=c(1,2,4))
}

windows(height=6, width=12)  # or quartz(), if you're using Mac
  layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))  # gives you 2 plots
  my.plot("Limed")
  my.plot("Unlimed")
```

[image]

Comment: That is incredible! Exactly what I was looking for. Tried to up vote, wont show it.

For my learning and future reference, aggregate allows calculations for multiple variables? I assume I could easily put median? I think I can see axes removes the normal axis to add custom ones using axis commands, I can get that under control with trial and error. 

You have already done so much for me but could you possibly explain the with(etc..) command to me. Such as what is it is doing at each step so I understand what and how to replicate. I think the == subsets & as.numeric plots the gene as dots?

Comment: @JasonWoodgate, much of that can be gleaned from reading the documentation. `aggregate()` computes the mean for each combination of `Treatment`, `Gene`, & `Liming`. You could compute the median or SD, etc, instead. If I had used `+` instead of `*`, you would have 3 lists of computed values, 1 for the means by treatment (ignoring gene & liming), etc. `==` yields `TRUE` for any row that has the same value on both sides; within the `which()` command, it lets you select the subset you want. `with()` just means I don't have to type `am$` for every variable.

Comment: Thank you so much.